# Clearing all observable bindings in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a control panel application right now, where each tool loads its own Javascript file, most of which contain some Knockout bindings. Knockout itself is being loaded in the document head, but tools are loaded asynchronous into a #body div, so my concern is that elements will continue to be bound, even after a different tool is loaded. I assume this would result in memory leaks and probably some glitches, if the same element is bound multiple times. Is it possible to clear all Knockout bindings at once, before I load a new tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general pattern that I would recommend is something like:

```
//obviously doesn't have to be an object literal
var viewModel = {
  currentTool: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, bind your page like:

```
<div data-bind="with: currentTool">
     ...content here
</div>
```

Now, when the page is initially bound, the area will not be rendered as `currentTool` is undefined, but KO will copy off the children to use as a "template".

When you populate the `currentTool` observable, it will render a copy of the elements and bind the content.

When you change `currentTool`, then KO will clean up the existing bindings and elements, and render/bind a new copy of the elements.

So, you only call `ko.applyBindings` once and continue to update `currentTool` based on what you want to display.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm having a little trouble following. Would you happen to know of a working example of this type of pattern? And thanks for your response, by the way.

Comment: So when I do var ViewModel = { etc } that will clear any bindings previously associated with ViewModel?

Comment: If you have a section bound against an observable like `currentTool` using the `with` binding, then Knockout will dispose and rebind that area whenever `currentTool` changes